# What is mass_t?

Tags: appexchange, installedpackage

I have this package installed: https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000018mbBEAQ

A custom object named "abc" was also installed as part of that installation (seems to be required?). What I´m confused about is the List Button within this object, "mass_t", that has this url: "https://chrischen.na6.visual.force.com/apex/massupdatewizard1".

I´ve never seen it elsewhere, the url leads nowhere, and the name doesn´t make what it is clear.

Comment: There is nothing strange over there, We can be define Custom List button with any name and the URL which it is pointing is Managed package apex Page URL, that's why it contains namespace prefix (`chrischen`) with it.
`https://chrischen.na6.visual.force.com/apex/massupdatewizard1`

Comment: @user2809299 `chrischen` is domain name here

Comment: @Oleksiy, that package which is mentioned by @EsiL, is a managed package and that button is also in Managed package so it is pointing a managed package Page that's why it is namespace prefix, if there is any custom domain then that should be appended before the manged package namespace, like this:
`https://mycustomdomain--chrischen.na6.visual.force.com/apex/massupdatewizard‌​1`

Comment: @user2809299, but what exactly is it´s purpose? I´m not seeing a massupdatewizard1 page.